# How to display user selected countries with coma separation?

Tags: laravel

**FORM**

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label>Country:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select  id="country-dd" name="country[]" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                            @foreach ($countries as $data)
                            <option value="{{$data->id}}">
                                {{$data->name}}
                            </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @if ($errors->has('country'))
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('country') }}</span>
                @endif
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

**BLADE FILE**

```
<tbody>
                                        @foreach($users as $user)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$user->countries->name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$user->states->name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$user->cities->name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$user->roles->name}}</td>
                                            <td><button><a href="{{route('edituser', $user->id)}}">EDIT</a></button></td>
                                            <td><button class="deleteuser" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" >DELETE</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                       </tbody>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function viewuser(){
        $this->authorize('Admin');
        $users = User::with(['roles', 'countries','states', 'cities'])->get();
        // dd($users);
        $roles = Role::all();
        $countries = Country::all();
        $states = State::all();
        $cities = City::all();
        return view('viewuser', compact('users', 'roles', 'countries', 'states', 'cities'));
    }
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/viewuser',[UserController::class, 'viewuser'])->name('viewuser');
```

If user selected 2 countries then both countries should get displayed on user listing table separated with coma. Please help me with the same. Thanks in advance.
NOTE: I have not defined foreign key for country in users table.

Comment: You have to use `$forloop`

Comment: @A.ANoman Can you please explain with code ??

Comment: you haven't  mentioned your relationship between user and country. i guess it's belongs to many relationship (it should be). so just loop over the relationship to print data as you are expecting. to get an example, you have to share your relationship code.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon This is user model
public function countries(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class, 'id');
    }

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: just use a foreach loop.  `@foreach ($user->countries as $country) <span>{{ $country->name }} @if (!$loop->last), @endif</span> @endforeach`